# Android "getter" is returning the wrong value

Tags: java, android

I have class B that extends class A and I am trying to access a variable from class A, but it's not returning the proper value.

(1) Variable declaration at the top of class A:

```
private int tripCount;
```

(2) I have a ViewModel observer in onCreate of class A that is looking for changes in a ROOM database and setting the tripCount variable accordingly:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // we are going to overwrite this
    // setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);

    baseViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(TripViewModel.class);
    baseViewModel.getAllTrips().observe(this, new Observer<List<TripEntity>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<TripEntity> trips) {
            tripCount = trips.size();
            Log.v("BaseActivity","tripCount: " + tripCount);
        }
    });
}
```

(3) Getter method for class A:

```
public int getTripCount() {
    return this.tripCount;
}
```

(4) Class B is extending class A and is trying to access the tripCount variable/value in the following way:

```
tripCount2 = super.getTripCount();
Log.v("TripActivity","tripCount: " + tripCount2);
```

The log is showing that tripCount2 from class B is 0 and tripCount from class A is > 0. Is there something wrong with my implementation here?

Comment: *tripCount from class A is > 0* if you don't post all the relevant code how you get help?

Comment: What am I missing? I thought I posted all the relevant code. @forpas

Comment: Where is the code that instantiates class B and how does tripCount in class A get its value?

Comment: Even if class `B` extends class `A` the instances of both are still completely separate objects and calling `super.getTripCount()` in a `B` instance doesn't return the value from an `A` instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question.

Instead of using the getter and setter methods, I made the tripCount variable "protected" so that I could access it from the subclass.